# aligning columns with row span in html

Tags: html

I have data like below

head
val1 val2 val3 val4
val5 val6 val7 val8
head
val5 val6 val7 val8
val2 val5 val6 val7

If the corresponding columns are empty for for any row ,Output I want is like below.

[out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/14O2m.png)

Comment: I think you forgot to add your try?

Answer (score 1):

You can use html-attribute `rowspan`,specify the number of rows a cell should span.

```html
<table style='border:1px solid black'>
  <tr>
    <td style='border:1px solid black' rowspan="2">headinng1</td>
    <td style='border:1px solid black'>val1 </td>
    <td style='border:1px solid black'>val2</td>
    <td style='border:1px solid black'>val3</td>
    <td style='border:1px solid black'>val4</td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
    <td style='border:1px solid black'>val1 </td>
    <td style='border:1px solid black'>val2</td>
    <td style='border:1px solid black'>val3</td>
    <td style='border:1px solid black'>val4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Just edited my question based on requirement. Can you please help? Can it be done for the above condition?

Comment: your problem is not properly cleared, please tell more

Answer (score -1):

Just edited Ibnelaiq's answer a little bit. is this what you want ?

```css
table,td{
    border: 1px solid gray;    
    border-collapse: collapse;
 
}

td{
    text-align: left;
    min-width: 80px ;
    min-height: auto;
    padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<table >
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">head</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>val3</td>
    <td >val4</td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
    <td >val1 </td>
    <td >val2</td>
    <td>val3</td>
    <td >val4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">head</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>val3</td>
    <td >val4</td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
    <td >val1 </td>
    <td >val2</td>
    <td>val3</td>
    <td >val4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: It is not valid, use standard html-attributes where height is not even described. Your solution work when height is know

Comment: use css insted of html-attribute. could you be a little more specific about the problem?